# Why am I getting a syntax error when using the Prepare() method? The problem goes away without the 'addCustCmd.Prepare();'

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I am trying to add customers to a MySQL database and then populate a DataGridView with the data. Without the **addCustCmd.Prepare();** method everything works fine. The customer is added to the database and my DGV is populated with new data. But I would like to add security to these inputs and prevent SQL injection, thus the Prepare(); method.

```
public static void addCust(string cCustomerName, string cAddress, string cAddress2, int cPhone, int cPostalCode, string cCity, string cCountry)
        {
            MySqlConnection addCustConn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            MySqlCommand addCustCmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO country VALUES " +
                "(NULL, @countryName, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP," +
                "@user, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @user);" +

                "INSERT INTO city " +
                "VALUES(NULL, @city, LAST_INSERT_ID(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @user, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
                "@user);" +

                "INSERT INTO address " +
                "VALUES(NULL, @address, @address2, LAST_INSERT_ID(), @postalCode, @phone, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @user," +
                "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @user);" +

                "INSERT INTO customer " +
                "VALUES(NULL, @customerName, LAST_INSERT_ID(), active, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @user," +
                "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @user);", addCustConn);
            addCustConn.Open();
            addCustCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countryName", cCountry);
            addCustCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", cCity);
            addCustCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", cAddress);
            addCustCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address2", cAddress2);
            addCustCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postalCode", cPostalCode);
            addCustCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", cPhone);
            addCustCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerName", cCustomerName);
            addCustCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", LoginForm.currentUser);

            addCustCmd.Prepare(); //Commenting this out allows the program to run no problems
            addCustCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            addCustConn.Close();
        }//end addCust
```

This is the error that pops up when I try to run it:
*"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO city VALUES(NULL, ?, LAST_INSERT_ID(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?, CURRENT' at line 1"*

Comment: I could be mistaken; however I question your comment… _”But I would like to add security to these inputs and prevent SQL injection, thus the Prepare(); method.”_ … I was not aware that the `Prepare` method “prevents” SQL injection. A possibly better approach is to NOT use `AddWithValue`. Instead, use the parameter collections `Add` method and supply the parameter with a “type” definition and “length”. `AddWithValue` will obviously work, however, my understanding it is best to define a “type” and “Length” with each parameter.

Comment: @JohnG [MySQL doesn't care about AddWithValue](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/); we avoid it for SQLServer but that doesn't apply here

Comment: @Chap just leave out the prepare call. The important part for preventing SQL injection is your good use of parameters, not the prepare

Comment: @Caius Jard … thanks for the info. I was under the impression that one reason to avoid using `AddWithValue` was the possible (behind-the-scenes) “narrowing/widening” of the data that “could” lead to possible data truncation in addition to possibly poorer performance due to the constant possible “narrowing/widening.” After perusing the link you provide, it appears to me that even MySql is still doing this “Convert/Coerce” behind-the-scenes.

Comment: But it also is clear from the link that using `AddWithValue` in MySql is perfectly fine and does not suffer from the same possible issues described for other SQL DBs using `AddWithValue`. I certainly am NO expert in the area and will do some further research when I get a chance to get a better understanding. And lastly I agree with you 100%, simply drop the `Prepare` statement as it has nothing to do with “preventing” SQL injection (at least that is my understanding) and apparently the code works without it.

Comment: `Prepare` is not necessary, parameterization is the only thing necessary. However, you **must** dispose your connection and command objects with `using`, or you may get left-open connections. Also you should look at verbatim multi-line strings (of the form `@"blah blah"`) which make it easier to use SQL queries directly in your code

Comment: Thanks everyone, this is all very useful info. I see that I misunderstood the function of Prepare().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each insert operation has to be a separate command to use prepared statements.

> SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by ; characters).

[Documentation source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: FWIW, this is a limitation of MySql.Data; the alternative .NET MySQL library (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/; disclaimer: lead author) can successfully `.Prepare()` and execute a compound statement.